# How to compare values greater than less than 0

Tags: php

I know this is pretty much simple idea, but I could not make it work.

`$addamout` values are 0.0001, 0.003, 0.006  so on and 1, 2, 3, etc.

`$addamout` ranges from 0.000001 to 10.

```
if ($addamout > 0 ) {
$contamout = $addamout;
}
else 
{
$contamout = $addamout * 10000;
}
```

Every time I run this query always  greater then condition is true, it never checks for values less than 0.0.

Comment: Don't you think 0.0000001 to 10 are all greater than 0.0?

Comment: 0.0001, 0.003, 0.006 ,0.000001 this values also greater than 0 only....

Comment: @FrankZhang , Cant say anything for my mistake

Comment: Here is a downvote for your hilarious indenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check again all values, which you have provided are greater than 0.
Thats why it never checks for values less than 0.0, because that condition never arises